# Nodemailer - MS Exchaneg server - Error unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send email from NodeJS using out office MS Exchange Mail server. with below code. And get error

Our Admin said no certificates are needed.

**Error:-**

```
$ node test2.js
Error :  { Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1048:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:628:8) code: 'ESOCKET', command: 'CONN' }
```

**NodeJS Code:-**

```
"use strict";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

async function main() {
    try {
        // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'host',
            port: 25,
            secure : false, // true for 465, false for other ports
            auth: {
                user: 'user',
                pass: 'password'
            }
        });

        // setup email data
        let mailOptions = {
            from: 'me@email.com',
            to: 'me@email.com',
            subject: 'Hey you, awesome!',
            html: '<b>This is bold text</b>',
            text: 'This is text version!'
        };

        // send mail with defined transport object
        let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
        console.log("Message sent: %s", JSON.stringify(info));

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error : ', error);
    }
}

main(); // For testing
```

Comment: which host are you using

Comment: It the company IP address or the machine name

Comment: try requireTLS: true

                    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
                      port: '587',
                      port: false,
                      requireTLS: true,
                      auth: {
                        user: 'user',
                        pass: 'pass'
                      }
                    });

change host to whatever host you are using

Comment: Thx, still the same issue mate.

Comment: i can give you working code but without explanation because i don't see what is wrong with your code

Comment: tell me if you want

Comment: Thanks mate we found the issue. Its now working. I would paste the code fix.

Comment: yeah i knew there was an issue in tls, but i did not know exactly what was needed, anyways , good luck mate!

Comment: Appreciate all you help and kind heart... :-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The below code change fixed the issue. Added this to the createTransport()

```
 tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
```

Code:-

```
   // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'host',
        port: 25,
        secure : false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: 'user',
            pass: 'password'
        },
        tls: {
            // do not fail on invalid certs
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        },
    });
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of time debugging our entire AWS Infrastructure. Thank you!

Comment: You saved the day bro!

Comment: Awesome, just the answer I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: bro, you nailed it! 
though, I still don't know what to do with this in C# library...:D