# What does ESOCKET error mean when I'm trying to send an email?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to send an email using nodemailer.

In my LAN there is a SMTP server listening on port 25. If I use telnet, it works fine.

My js script is:

```
this.transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            return callback(error, null);
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(info));

        return callback(null, true);
});
```

It only prints: {"code":"ESOCKET","command":"CONN"}. What does it mean?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/889#issuecomment-488267379 (and it's follow-ups):

> same problem here. resolved it by using IP address as host, see
>   https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#general-options

For us it seems to be related to throttling as circa 140 messages go through in a batch while the remainder get this error (and all are being sent to the same email address, so no issue re: bad email addresses). Changing to an IP didn't solve the issue (maybe because the SMTP is on AWS?).

What did eventually work for us was this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55187729/235704

> The below code change fixed the issue. Added this to the
>   createTransport()
>
> ```
> tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
> ```
>
> Code:-
>
> ```
> // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
> let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
>     host: 'host',
>     port: 25,
>     secure : false, // true for 465, false for other ports
>     auth: {
>         user: 'user',
>         pass: 'password'
>     },
>     tls: {
>         // do not fail on invalid certs
>         rejectUnauthorized: false
>     },
> });
> ```

It seems that, in our providers case, their certificates do not cover all of the IPs they are being served from on AWS.

Comment: saved me a lot of time